# Compare 2 PHP arrays and filter out results

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've been struggling for a while now. I have 2 arrays that I want to compare with each other. 
A user array and a lesson array. The Keys in the lesson array are the ID's of that lesson

**Lesson Array:**

```
Array(
    // The key in this array ([143] or [13]) is the lesson ID each lesson contains one ore more topics
    [143] => Array (
        [0] => 315 // example: 315 is a topic ID within lesson 143
        [1] => 311
        [2] => 176
        [3] => 145
    )

    [13] => Array (
        [0] => 27
        [1] => 25
    )
)
```

The user array contains only the information about which topics that user has completed. Topic with lesson ID's that are not completed don't exist in this array.

Main question: I want to compare the topic ID's of the user array to the Lesson array. And I want to put the topics that aren't completed in a seperate array.

**User array**

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [143] => Array (
            [145] => 1 // (this 1 means it is completed, this key is a topic ID)
            [176] => 1
        )
    )

    [1] => Array (
        [13] => Array (
            [25] => 1
        )
    )

)
```

In this example above the result i want to get is an array with non matching id's like:

```
$result = array( 143 => array(311,315), 13 => array(27))
```

I hope it's a little bit clear.

If anyone can point me out in the right direction I'll be very glad! I tried a lot of things but to post them all here it's not clarifying the main question.

Comment: you have start with user array, check the first index `143` is in the lesson array or not? if yes then check the values, if not then store it in the `result array`.

Comment: The example result you gave us lists only topics which weren't completed by any user. Is this really what you want or would it not be more realistic to output one such array of missing topics per user?

Comment: The $result is already containing information about an unique user. So I have to know the topics that weren't completed so i can make the user start where he was left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use `array_keys` and `array_diff`. Online compile at [My answer](https://3v4l.org/6i6NU)

**Arrays**

```
$lesson = array(
    "143" => array("315", "311", "176", "145"),
    "13" => array("27", "25")
);

$user = array(
    array("143" => array("145" => "1", "176" => "1")),
    array("13" => array("25" => "1"))
);
```

**Mechanism/ process**

```
$result = array();
foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        $result[$key2] = array_diff($lesson[$key2], array_keys($value2));
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output**

```
Array
    (
        [143] => Array
        (
            [0] => 315
            [1] => 311
        )
        [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 27
        )
)
```

Comment: Nice one! I'm going to check that out immediately. But it looks like it's exactly what i meant.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing I'd do is modify the User array using probably array_flip() so that I'd end up with something like this:

```
Array (
   [0] => Array (

            [143] => Array (
                [0] => 145
                [1] => 176
            )

   )

   [1] => Array (

            [13] => Array (
                [0] => 25
            )

   )
```

Once that's done, all you have to do is use the array_diff() function to compare the two arrays and you'll have whatever element is only in the first array:

```
$diff = array_diff($lesson[143], $user[0][143])
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: `array_flip` on User produce can not work, because all values are 1.